# how to link my menu item to a blog in nopcommerce?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

I have created a blog named BlogPost1 in nopcommerce2.65 admin section. I checked the database and saw that its `id` in the table is '3'

I would like to link this blogpost page created in admin section to my menu item link in my main menu. How can I do it in MVC Razor?

Can I directly connect it or must I make changes in model and contoller of Blog? Is it possible using this code? I tried this but didnt work. Is there any mistake in what I do ?

`<li><a href="Html.ActionLink(article.Title, new { controller = "Blog", action = "BlogPost", id = \d+ })">Blog Post 1</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at Views/Blog/List.cshtml, you'll see this kind of code:

```
<a class="blog-title" href="@Url.RouteUrl("BlogPost", new { SeName = item.SeName })">@item.Title</a>
```

Which tells you everything you want to know about linking to a Blog Post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this one.

```
<li><a href="http://linkofyourblogpost">Blog Post 1</a></li>
```

Add this to Views> Common> Menu